# Unit Test Case for updateOrderStatus($orderId)

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I am new in writing unit testing in Magento 2. I want to write a test case for getting an order by the **`order_id`**.

Below is my model function:

```
/**
 * Initialize dependencies
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $json
 * @param  Data $helper
 * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param Helper $websiteCheck
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    Json $json,
    Helper $helper,
    Curl $curl,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    Helper $websiteCheck,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
) {
    $this->json = $json;
    $this->helper = $helper;
    $this->curl = $curl;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_websiteCheck = $websiteCheck;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_storeId = $this->_websiteCheck->getStoreId();
}

public function updateOrderStatus($orderId)
    {    
       if ($orderId) {
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
            $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
            $order->setStatus(self::SENT_TO_WAREHOUSE);
            $comment = "Order Status Changed to Sent to Warehouse";
            try {
                $order->addStatusToHistory(
                    self::SENT_TO_WAREHOUSE,
                    $comment
                );
                $this->orderRepository->save($order);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
            }
}
```

I have used  **`\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository repository`**,

Below is my test case functions:

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

protected function setup(): void
    {
           $this->_orderRepositoryInterface = $this->getMockBuilder(OrderRepositoryInterface::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->orderMock = $this->getMockBuilder(OrderInterface::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMockForAbstractClass();

          $this->objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);

          $this->model = $this->objectManager->getObject(
            \ModelClassName::class,
            [
                'helper' => $this->helper,
                'json' => $this->json,
                'orderRepositoryInterface' => $this->_orderRepositoryInterface,
                'orderInterface' => $this->_orderInterface,
                'orderFactory' => $this->orderFactory
            ]
        );
}

public function testUpdateOrderStatus()
{
    $orderID = '57956';
    $this->_orderRepositoryInterface->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get')
        ->willReturn($this->orderMock);

    $this->orderMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('setState')->with("processing")
        ->willReturnSelf();

    $this->orderMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('setStatus')->with("sent_to_warehouse")
        ->willReturnSelf();

    $this->_orderRepositoryInterface->expects($this->once())
        ->method('save')
        ->with($this->orderMock)
        ->willReturnSelf();

    $this->assertEquals(true, $this->model->updateOrderStatus($orderID));
```

**`$this->model`** is my original model class for which i am writing Test Unit.
I am receiving error like below :

> Error: Call to a member function setState() on null

As i said i am new in writing unit tests, so if anyone can get idea from above code then it will helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `$this->orderMock` as you added `orderRepositoryInterface' => $this->_orderRepositoryInterface` in `setup:void` funntion constructor.

Comment: I have already tried that $this->orderMock passed into Constructor in Test class's Setup but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Can you please send original class constructor?

Comment: I have added constructor in the original question, can you please check that and let me know what i am doing wrong.